# Programmatically track subdomains in different view for google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I've a site which allows users to register, creating a store front page like a shopping cart for them to customize. Each page is a subdomain of the main page, and is coded using one jsp.

Eg: User creates store front page named "abc", his store front page will be abc.mydomain.com

Is there a way to track these different subdomains individually separately using google analytics programmitically?

I've googled and currently did it by creating views and filters, but as i researched there are no way to create these views and filters programmitically, having to go to the google analytics page to create at there. I saw there is also a limit of views one can create thus am wondering if there are any other solution to this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtProfileGuide) to create, update, and delete profiles, but as you've found out there is a limit of 50 profiles (views) per non-premium account. I would say to use advanced segments to segment out hostnames, but again there is also a [limit of 100 advanced segments per view.](http://www.cardinalpath.com/limits-to-advanced-segmentation-in-google-analytics/) One idea (and I haven't tested this) could be that when a user creates an account, they create a sub subdomain abc.foo.mydomain.com, and after there have been 100 sub subdomains created, switch the subdomain to bar.mydomain.com, etc. This way, you could get 5000 possible combinations. Again, you would want to test.

One other option, and this is similar to what Shopify does, is to have the user input their own GA account through the admin - but the downfall of this is that you (the site designer) wouldn't have visibility into that subdomains data.

Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to implement filters by subdomain on one profile and extract each subdomain data information by its own?

Comment: If anyone still reads this answer... is it still true that you can only have 50 profiles/views per account? I don't think this is the case. You can have up to 100 accounts, up to 50 properties per account and up to 25 views per property. (I am referring to the free/non-premium version)